# Control What Advanced Installer Puts In Program Files

Tags: windows, advanced-installer

I create an Advanced Installer Template that has a Custom Exe attached to the process.

Advanced installer creates an msi with the custom exe embedded into it.

When I run the msi and look in Add/Remove Programs there are 2 entries the installer
itself and the custom exe.

I want only the installer itself listed there not the custom exe.

How can I accomplish this?

[image]

I map a key to delete and it only gives an option to delete values in the key? I want to delete the entire key

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to remove the Control Panel registry key for your custom exe product. Just search in regedit for a path like this: **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Product**

Then in "Registry" page of your setup project (in Advanced Installer tool), create the path of the above reg key, right click on it -> Properties -> Operations -> check Remove this key ... option with Remove on - component install.

This way when your current setup package installs it will delete the registries associated with your custom EXE product.

Comment: This seems to work when I do it manually, but the Component install checkbox asks you to choose a value ( see above) I want to remove the whole key.

Comment: That option should remove the entire key too. In what regards the component dropbox just leave this as it is. You should just select a component that it is always installed (at installation time). When the selected component is installed the remove action will be executed too.